# Attractors in random dynamics

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, random-functions

Let $\Delta$ be  the interval $[-1,1]$, then we can consider the probability space $(\Delta , \mathcal{B}(\Delta),\nu)$, where $\mathcal{B}(\Delta)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\nu$ is equal half of the Lebesgue measure.

Then we can endow the space $\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}:= \{ (\omega_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}};\  \omega_n \in \Delta, \ \forall \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\Delta^{\mathbb{N}})$ (Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}$ induced by the  product topology) and the probability measuare $\nu^{\mathbb{N}}$ in the measurable space$(\Delta^{\mathbb{N}},\mathcal{B}(\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}))$, such that
$$\nu^{\mathbb{N}} \left(A_1\times A_2\times \ldots \times A_n \times \prod_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \Delta\right)=\nu(A_1) \cdot \ldots\cdot \nu(A_n). $$

Now, let $\sigma>2/(3\sqrt{3})$ be a real number, and define 
$$x_-^* = \text{The unique real root of the polynomial }x^ 3+ \sigma = x, $$
$$x_+^* = \text{The unique real root of the polynomial }x^ 3- \sigma = x, $$
it is easy to see that $x_+^* = -x_-^*$.

We can then define the function 
$$h:\mathbb{N}\times \Delta^ \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}  $$
in the following recursive way,

- $h(0,(\omega_n)_{n},x) = x$, $\forall\ (\omega_n)_n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall\ x\in \mathbb{R}$;
- $h(i+1,(\omega_n)_{n},x) = \sqrt[3]{h(i,(\omega_n)_{n},x) + \sigma \omega_i}.$

This way we are for, every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(\omega_n)_n\in\Delta^\mathbb {N}$, defining the following sequence
$$\left\{x, \sqrt[3]{x + \sigma \omega_1},\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{x + \sigma \omega_1}+\sigma w_2},\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{x + \sigma \omega_1}+\sigma w_2} + \sigma w_3}, \ldots \right\}.$$

Using Mathematica I did some numerical experiments and seems like that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| h(n,(\omega_n)_n, x^*_+) - h(n,(\omega_n)_n, x^*_-) \right| = 0,\ \text{for $\nu^{\mathbb{N}}$-almost surely $(\omega_n)_n$} \in \Delta^{\mathbb{N}}. $$

**Can anyone tell me, or present me a good reason why this should happen?**

---

### Numerical evidences

Below this paragraph you can find my Mathematica code, imputing a value of $\sigma$ and a number of iterations ($b$) this program has as output two discrete plot, the first one is the discrete plot of the sequences $h(\cdot, (\omega_n)_n, x_+^ *)$ and $h(\cdot, (\omega_n)_n, x_-^ *)$ in the same plot, the second one is a discrete plot of the difference $h(\cdot , (\omega_n)_n, x_+^ *) - h(\cdot , (\omega_n)_n, x_-^ *)$, for some random sequence $(\omega_n)_n$.

```
\[Sigma] = 2/(3*Sqrt[3]) + 0.15; *Insert here your value of sigma*
b = 10000; *Insert here your the number of iterations*
A = Solve[x^3 + \[Alpha] == x , x, Reals];
B = Solve[x^3 - \[Alpha] == x , x, Reals];
y = x /. A[[1]];
z = x /. B[[1]];
W = Table[RandomReal[{-\[Sigma], \[Sigma]}], {i, 1, b}]; 
P = RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == CubeRoot[x[n] + W[[n]]], x[1] == y}, 
x, {n, 1, b} ];
Q = RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == CubeRoot[x[n] + W[[n]]], x[1] == z}, 
x, {n, 1, b} ];
DiscretePlot[{P[[i]], Q[[i]]}, {i, 1, b}, PlotRange -> {{1, b}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]
DiscretePlot[Q[[i]] - P[[i]], {i, 1, b},PlotRange -> {{1, b}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Brown]
```

**Example 1**: $\sigma = 1$ and $b= 50$
[image]

**Example 2**: $\sigma = \frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}} +0.15$ and $b= 100000.$

[image]

for some reason when $\sigma$ is big, the convergence of $\left| h(n,(\omega_n)_n, x^*_+) - h(n,(\omega_n)_n, x^*_-) \right|$ seems to occur "faster", and I do not have idea why this happens.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a monotone continuous random dynamical system such that the underlying Markov process is uniquely ergodic, it admits a unique random fixed point. The standard proof goes as follows: by monotonicity and continuity, the bounded set attractor $A$ is such that $A_+ = \sup A$ and $A_- = \inf A$ are random fixed points. Since the law of $A_\pm$ is a (and therefore the by unique ergodicity) invariant measure, one must have $A_+ = A_-$ almost surely.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was looking exactly for a result as you described "Since this is a monotone continuous random dynamical system such that the underlying Markov process is uniquely ergodic, it admits a unique random fixed point"  Could you recommend me some reference so I can learn about it?

Comment: See for example the list of references in Section 1.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1340.pdf.

Comment: Thx you so much.

Comment: Can you please me definite the "underlying Markov process" I am not sure about you mean by that?

Comment: I think that is the family of process $$\{\Phi_{n}^{x}(\omega) := h(n,x,\omega)\}, $$ with transition probability $$P_{n}(x,\Gamma) = \int_{\Omega} 1_{\Gamma}\circ h(n,\omega,x)\ \text{d} \nu^{\mathbb{N}}(\omega), $$ but I am not sure.

Comment: how do you know "the underlying Markov process is uniquely ergodic"

Comment: Just for the records I really would like to know why   "the underlying Markov process is uniquely ergodic".

Comment: The threshold $2/(3\sqrt 3)$ is precisely the one beyond which one can reach an arbitrary neighbourhood of $x_+^*$ (say) with positive probability, starting from any initial condition. It is then an exercise to show that the hypotheses of Harris's theorem are satisfied, which gives exponential ergodicity.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I think that I am confusing something. The result that you cited guarantees us the existence of only one stationary probability. Why this implies that exists only one random fixed point? Using the random fixed point how do you induce a stationary probability? I understand that $\nu^{\mathbb{N}}\times \delta_{a(\omega)}$ is an ergodic invariant measure, but this is not related to the stationary measure (at least in my point of view).

Comment: Please reread my answer...

Comment: I was reading your paper "Yet Another Look at Harris’ Ergodic Theorem for Markov Chains" (very good ideas), to understand what do you mean by "Harris's theorem". Do you think that in my case assumptions $1$ and $2$ are satisfied in my context?